# Richfaces colorPicker not show all components

Tags: jboss, richfaces, color-picker

I'm using  of Richfaces to implement the color picker function in a Web App, but it doesn't show any text box field to enter RGB manually, pick color using pointer is the only way to choose color. Anyone knows what the issue is? 
Fyi, I'm using Richfaces 3.3.3.
It should be like this: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/colorPicker.jsf?c=colorPicker

But in my app, it only shows this:

[image: colorPicker]

Comment: Have you checked the HTML? The input fields are not rendered conditionally.

Comment: @Makhiel I don't see any problem in HTML page. I also tried to copy the whole sample code but the problem was still there. I think the root cause could be in my project setup related to jboss, richfaces... but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: So the inputs are there?